# How do I rewrite this URL for .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have many tag URL's that need to be changed to a new domain permalink structure.

I need some help please with a rewrite rule for my .htaccess file.

Old URL:

```
domain.com/tags/TAGNAME.html
```

New URL:

```
domain.com/tags/TAGNAME/
```

Where TAGNAME changes, respectively.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this should be an external redirect, not a URL rewrite, as your question suggests? To redirect from the old URL to the new URL?

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root, try the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tags/([\w-]+)\.html$ /tags/$1/ [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) status to 301 (if that is the intention) only once you have confirmed this is working.

This assumes your `TAGNAME` consists of only the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`, `-`.

Alternatively, if `/tags` is a physical directory then you could create a `/tags/.htaccess` file and use the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ /tags/$1/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Yes! That did it. I took your first option and modified it with the trailing forward slash, and that worked perfect. I think your solution worked more than the other one offered because you preserve the tags/ at the beginning, so it's not interfering with my other rewrite rules. Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, I've added the trailing slash in my answer (sorry, missed that!). The other answer had the _old_ and _new_ URLs reversed initially, but it's also a "rewrite" (as you prompted in your question), not a "redirect" - so it wouldn't have "corrected" the URL.

Comment: When I wrote my question, I had not thought about my choice of words - rewrite versus redirect - when I was indeed looking for a redirect. I will be much more clearer in my future questions. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1
```

Comment: @Daniel could you please check my updated answer? You can test it here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/